# Swift - scheduledTimer stopwatch hours portion not working

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

Bear with me I picked up Swift and Xcode a week ago (Im creating an app to learn Swift during my holidays)

I created a timer using scheduledTimer to act as an stopwatch. The seconds and minutes are running fine but I can't get the hours to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
currentTime = 0
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in

    self.currentTime += 1

    let hoursPortion = String(format: "%02d", CGFloat(self.currentTime) * 60)
    let minutesPortion = String(format: "%02d", self.currentTime / 60)
    let secondsPortion = String(format: "%02d", self.currentTime % 60)
    //let tenPortion = String(format: "%d", self.currentTime * 10 % 10)
    self.TimerDisplay.text = "\(hoursPortion):\(minutesPortion):\(secondsPortion)"
}
```

Comment: If current time is elapsed seconds then hours is `currentTime/3600`. I don't know why you are multiplying by 20. This approach is probably not the best anyway; Timer is not accurate. A better approach would be to create a `Date` when the stopwatch starts and the compute the difference between that date and "now" when your timer ticks. `DateComponents` can help you to get the fields from the date.

Comment: Yes thats true the 20 should have been 3600, but I set it to 20 so I didn't have to wait an hour to see if it worked. I set the hoursPortion to multiply because I thought 1 hours = 3600 seconds.

Comment: No, you want to divide, since 1 hour = 3600 seconds; If `currentTime` = 3600 then that is 1 hour, so `currentTime / 3600`

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you shouldn't try to keep track of the time yourself. Let the system figure out how much time has elapsed. And, I'd be inclined to use [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) to format the string for you, too:

```
@IBOutlet weak var elapsedLabel: UILabel!

weak var timer: Timer?

private var formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    return formatter
}()

private func startTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()      // stop prior timer, if any

    let startTime = Date()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.elapsedLabel.text = self?.formatter.string(from: startTime, to: Date())
    }
}

deinit {
    timer?.invalidate()
}
```

BTW, it’s a subtle point, but please notice the use of `[weak self]` in the `Timer` closure’s capture list. In the absence of that, you have a variation of a strong reference cycle because timers don't stop until you `invalidate` them, but the view controller's `deinit` cannot be called until the timer's strong reference to the view controller is resolved. By using `[weak self]` capture list in the closure, we break that cycle, allowing the view controller to be deallocated when it's dismissed and it will stop the timer for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best approach as the timer is not guaranteed to be accurate enough, it will drift over time. A better approach is to record a start time and use the calendar functions to give you the elapsed time. e.g.

```
        let startTime = Date()
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
            let now = Date()
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: startTime, to: now)

            guard let hoursPortion = components.hour, let minutesPortion = components.minute, let secondsPortion = components.second
            else {
                preconditionFailure("Should not happen")
            }

            self.TimerDisplay.text = "\(hoursPortion):\(minutesPortion):\(secondsPortion)"
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment that was useful! I didn't end up using it for the project I was working on, but im testing some things and got it to work. How to you format the timer to show 00:02:20 for 2 minutes and 20 seconds?

Comment: Use the String(format:) approach that you used in your initial question, or use the DateComponentsFormatter suggestion from Rob.